# new to board bring up some confusion;in the uboot/board folder,but my vendor name - lichee Pi Zero is not specified

Tags: arm, embedded-linux

I have done some projects in linux. I have a current requirement which requires bring up of ARM board (Lichee Pi Zero 1GHz Cortex-A7 512Mbit DDR Development Board Mini PC). I am interested in doing this kind of bring up and embedded development, but I am new to bring up.I went through the articles
https://elinux.org/images/2/2a/Schulz-how-to-support-new-board-u-boot-linux.pdf
and
https://www.imx6rex.com/software/how-to-start-with-linux-and-uboot/
what I understand is that-
i must configure linux kernel with the drivers
then I must configure the uboot
then configure the kernel with debug symbols
then transfer it to tftpboot
then load that into mmc card

But
I do not understand where I get uboot from. there are confusing links regarding that.
I tried git clone -b  git://git.toradex.com/u-boot-toradex.git
it gives error
bash: git://git.toradex.com/u-boot-toradex.git: No such file or directory

Now I am running the command
sudo git clone https://git.toradex.com/u-boot-toradex.git
it failed with error error: Unable to find 29cc6619eaba7a5caaee80709f04897a6030ceca under https://git.toradex.com/u-boot-toradex.git

I downloaded uboot from https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot
Please correct me if anything is wrong

where I will get linux kernel from? Should I download from net or ask client. He was talking about some linux SDK.

What phase does toolchain/cross-compilation come in. How to do that? Any references?

There is ROM loader, SPL and uboot which loads kernel into arm. But nothing is mentioned about SPL in the above links

---

in the uboot/board folder, there are various vendor names, but my vendor name - lichee Pi Zero is not specified. Should I make a new folder for my vendor, and also update the Kconfig files?

Comment: The first place to look for suitable source is the board manufacturer's web site.  It took me less than a minute to find [Build U-Boot for LicheePi Zero](https://licheepizero.us/build--uboot-for-licheepi-zero) using Google.

Answer (score 0):

The LicheePI Zero is currently supported by the mainline u-boot.
 
A procedure for building it from scratch would then be:

```
git clone --branch v2019.07  http://git.denx.de/u-boot.git
wget "https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/8.3-2019.03/binrel/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-eabi.tar.xz?revision=402e6a13-cb73-48dc-8218-ad75d6be0e01&la=en" -O gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-eabi.tar.xz
tar Jxf gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-eabi.tar.xz
CROSS_COMPILE=$(pwd)/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi- ARCH=arm make -C u-boot mrproper LicheePi_Zero_defconfig all
```

The u-boot executable and friends should be available in the u-boot directory:

```
ls -gGl  u-boot/u-boot.*
-rw-rw-r-- 1  368187 Sep 20 14:08 u-boot/u-boot.bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1   12140 Sep 20 14:07 u-boot/u-boot.cfg
-rw-rw-r-- 1    7395 Sep 20 14:08 u-boot/u-boot.cfg.configs
-rw-rw-r-- 1    6647 Sep 20 14:08 u-boot/u-boot.dtb
-rw-rw-r-- 1    6790 Sep 20 14:08 u-boot/u-boot.dtb.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1  368251 Sep 20 14:08 u-boot/u-boot.img
-rw-rw-r-- 1    2343 Sep 20 14:08 u-boot/u-boot.lds
-rw-rw-r-- 1  556881 Sep 20 14:08 u-boot/u-boot.map
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1084778 Sep 20 14:08 u-boot/u-boot.srec
-rw-rw-r-- 1  147508 Sep 20 14:08 u-boot/u-boot.sym
```

I hope this helps.